# Titanium appcelerator module not found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I'm facing an error when building my titanium appcelerator application for android, below are modules installed :

**- modules**
Android > com.pushwoosh.module and dk.napp.drawer

**tiapp.xml**

```
<modules>
    <module platform="iphone">dk.napp.drawer</module>
    <module platform="android">dk.napp.drawer</module>
...
```

When i build the app, and run it from device i get following error :

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [60613,103255] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,103256] - In ti:/module.js:303,2
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,103256] - Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: dk.napp.drawer
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,103256] - Source:  throw new Error("Requested module not found: " + request); // TODO Set 'code' property to 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' to match Node?
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:303: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: dk.napp.drawer
[ERROR] :  ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

So i don't know why the app doesn't found the dk.app.drawer module, here is a screenshot of all modules:

[image: Modules]

Thanks again for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot you only show the version 1.2.4 which is the iOS version. Did you add the android version too?
https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/tree/master/android/dist

Comment: Hey, 
i didn't know that this list exists, thank miga, you saved my day.